# Any specific tools to development the application using HTML 5

Tags: html

Any specific tools are there to develop the application using html 5?

I had used Aptana studio, I feel it is not fully user friendly tool to write a html 5 application.

Comment: Yes, i am looking any editor is available to develop the application.

Comment: notepad++ is my favorite on windows.

Comment: can we debug the application in notepad++ ?

Comment: You use the browser to "debug" html5 but the editor can be any of your favorite text-editors or dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://marakana.com/bookshelf/html5_tutorial/index.html take a look at that for starter points.

This is a great, easy to read tutorial which will almost definitely help you learn HTML5 and CSS - http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/30-days-to-learn-html-and-css-a-free-tuts-premium-course/

For debugging, you can use Chromes developer tools (F12 on the keyboard) or the same on Opera & Internet Explorer. For Firefox download "Firebug".

Another "debugging" tool is http://html5.validator.nu/ which will validate your HTML and show any errors.

Notepad++ is a great free app to start developing HTML5 on, you can also use others, for example [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) is a great IDE. For one with a GUI, I'd advise purchasing [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html), it is expensive but I say it's the best for learners.